# How to train Huggingface TFT5ForConditionalGeneration model?

Tags: tensorflow, huggingface-transformers

My code is as follows:

```
batch_size=8
sequence_length=25
vocab_size=100
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import T5Config, TFT5ForConditionalGeneration
configT5 = T5Config(
    vocab_size=vocab_size,
    d_ff =512, 
)  
model = TFT5ForConditionalGeneration(configT5)

model.compile(
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
)
input = tf.random.uniform([batch_size,sequence_length],0,vocab_size,dtype=tf.int32)
labels = tf.random.uniform([batch_size,sequence_length],0,vocab_size,dtype=tf.int32)
input = {'inputs': input, 'decoder_input_ids': input}
model.fit(input, labels)
```

It generates an error:

> logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape
> [1600,64] and labels shape [200]    [[node
> sparse_categorical_crossentropy_3/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits
> (defined at C:\Users\FA.PROJECTOR-MSK\Google Диск\Colab
> Notebooks\PoetryTransformer\experiments\TFT5.py:30) ]]
> [Op:__inference_train_function_25173]  Function call stack:
> train_function

I dont understand - why the model returns a tensor of [1600, 64]. According to https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/t5.html#tft5forconditionalgeneration model returns [batch_size, sequence_len, vocab_size].

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to call `fit()` because of non-standard signature of `call()` method of TFT5ForConditionalGeneration. I have to override `train_step()` to make TFT5 working. See here - https://colab.research.google.com/github/snapthat/TF-T5-text-to-text/blob/master/snapthatT5/notebooks/TF-T5-Datasets%20Training.ipynb#scrollTo=cgxRVn34Z0wb